# Why does the following python code gives unexpected results sometimes?

Tags: python, cron, seek

I wrote a small script to fetch some data from a website and store it in a file. The data is fetched in a variable "content".

```
try:
    content = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
except:
    content = ""
```

The file has a few short phrases, each on a new line. I intend to simply update the last line of the file every time I run the script. And so I'm using the following code:

```
try:
    f = open("MYFILENAME","r+")                     # open file for reading and writing    
    lines = f.readlines()
    replace_index = len(lines[-1])              
    f.seek(long(int(f.tell())-replace_index))       # should move to the start of last line
    # content[start:end] has no "\n" for sure.
    f.write(content[start:end] + " " + now + "\n")
except Exception as exc:
    print "This is an exception",exc
finally:
    f.close()
```

Now, I use the crontab to run this script every minute and update "MYFILENAME".
But the script gives weird behavior **sometimes**,i.e., instead of replacing the last line, it appends a new line to the file. These *sometimes* are usually associated with me restarting the computer or re-using it after putting it on sleep.

If original file was:

```
xyz
abc
bla bla bla
1 2 3
```

I'm expecting the output to be:

```
xyz
abc
bla bla bla
my_new_small_phrase
```

Instead, sometimes I get:

```
xyz
abc
bla bla bla
1 2 3
my_new_small_phrase
```

What is wrong with the above code? (I'm using both *crontabs* and *seek and tell* functions for the first time, so I'm not sure about either of them.)
Or is it something to do with the **"\n"** at the end of write() function?

Comment: Are you using "plain" `cron` or one clone `anacron`, `fcron` and so on?

Comment: In addition, how do you deal with `\n` in the "content"?

Comment: I'm using "plain" cron. I've written the "python myscript.py" command in the crontab file.

Comment: "\n" inside content shouldn't be a problem. I'm actually only writing a slice of content, and I'm sure there is no "\n" inside that slice.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to (1) show a typical example of "content" read from your URL (2) the expected output (3) the "weird" output (4) the full significant part of your code. I don't see any "slice" here.

Comment: thanks! I've edited the question, I hope it makes it clear.

Comment: If you read the data every minute from the website could it be that the file changes on server while you read it and you get a "mixed" version? Could it be that the downloaded file sometimes has an additional newline at the end?

Comment: @MichaelButscher yes, the file does change frequently sometimes (during matches: I'm simply fetching the current score into a file), but still I don't think that should be the reason as even when its not changing, and I awake my computer from sleep, within a few minutes, a lot of lines get accumulated in the file. 
Also, I'm pretty sure there's no "\n" at the end at any instant.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do it like this:

```
lines = open("filename", "r").readlines()
del lines[-1]

f = open("filename", "w")
for line in lines:
 f.write(line)

f.write("new content")
f.close()
```

Comment: thanks for the much simpler way to do it. :). However, can you please tell why the above code is behaving in a strange manner?